# How to filter stdout in python logging

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I'm using library 'logging' to log info and warning messages in my scripts, is there anyway I can filter out passwords (I have more than one passwords and would like to get them replaced with asterisks) while printing into stdout?

Comment: How is the "password" getting sent to logging?

Comment: passwords to be masked are stored in a list.

Comment: can  you provide an example of when passwords are getting printed? (Don't post actual passwords)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to filter out specific words contained in your password list from the `stdout` stream (that's where `logging.DEBUG` and `logging.INFO` messages go) and the `stderr` stream (that's where `logging.WARNING`, `logging.ERROR` and `logging.CRITICAL` messages go), you can replace the original streams with a simple class that replaces the critical words before writing them out:

```
class PasswordFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, strings_to_filter, stream):
        self.stream = stream
        self.strings_to_filter = strings_to_filter

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr_name)

    def write(self, data):
        for string in self.strings_to_filter:
            data = re.sub(r'\b{0}\b'.format(string), '*' * len(string), data)
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.stream.flush()

    def flush(self):
        self.stream.flush()
```

Replace the original streams with the filtered ones like that:

```
top_secret_passwords = ['do not tell me', 'I am secret', 'important', 'foo',
                        'foobar']
sys.stdout = PasswordFilter(top_secret_passwords, sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = PasswordFilter(top_secret_passwords, sys.stderr)
```

Now, set up logging and write some log messages:

```
# set up your logging after activating the filter, won't work otherwise
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug('You cannot see me anymore: {0}'.format(top_secret_passwords[0]))
logger.info('You cannot see me anymore: {0}'.format(top_secret_passwords[1]))
logger.warning('You cannot see me anymore: {0}'.format(top_secret_passwords[2]))
logger.error('You cannot see me anymore: {0}'.format(top_secret_passwords[3]))
logger.critical('You cannot see me anymore: {0}'.format(top_secret_passwords[4]))
```

The output will look like this:

```
DEBUG:__main__:You cannot see me anymore: **************
INFO:__main__:You cannot see me anymore: ***********
WARNING:__main__:You cannot see me anymore: *********
ERROR:__main__:You cannot see me anymore: ***
CRITICAL:__main__:You cannot see me anymore: ******
```

Comment: This does not work for strings that contain special regex chars.  Also, re.escape() should not be used in re.sub().  A simpler solution is to use `new_string = len(string) * "*"`  and then `data.replace(string, new_string)` within write().

Answer (score 3):

### Filter out patterns, without printing a newline

A modification to @Dirk's Filter class.

This version will not print out any line which matches the input pattern. It will also not print out a newline break after a filtered line has been skipped

```py
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, stream, re_pattern):
        self.stream = stream
        self.pattern = re.compile(re_pattern) if isinstance(re_pattern, str) else re_pattern
        self.triggered = False

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr_name)

    def write(self, data):
        if data == '\n' and self.triggered:
            self.triggered = False
        else:
            if self.pattern.search(data) is None:
                self.stream.write(data)
                self.stream.flush()
            else:
                # caught bad pattern
                self.triggered = True

    def flush(self):
        self.stream.flush()

# example
sys.stdout = Filter(sys.stdout, r'Read -1')  # filter out any line which contains "Read -1" in it


# No lines (or newline breaks) will be printed to stdout after running the below.
for _ in range(10):
  print('Read -1 expected 4096')
```